# How to add positive and negative totals from the same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using sql server with a table called `dbo.over_short` and I am trying to figure out how to add totals from the same column.

I have a column called `FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT` it has design of decimal(10,2).

In this field there are positive numbers (ex 608.90) neutral numbers like (ex 0.00) and negative numbers like (ex -608.90).

Is it possible to add all the positive numbers together and all the negative numbers together (numbers starting with a minus) seperately.

To basically have a report of how much was over and how much was negative? (Without having the negatives subtract from the positive. Two separate totals)

```
select 
  ID,
  TRANSACTION_DATE,
  ASSOCIATE_ID,
  AGENCY_CODE,     
  FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT
from
  dbo.over_short
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `sum(case when FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT >= 0 then FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT else 0 end)` and `sum(case when FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT < 0 then FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT else 0 end)` but you need to group the data for `sum` to work.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Actually, it should be possible to take a sum over the entire table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not if they're pulling the `id` field as shown :) my guess would be this is required for a date range. But the poster can confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT >= 0
             THEN FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS pos_amount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT < 0
             THEN FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS neg_amount
FROM dbo.over_short;
```

You could also use a similar query along with `GROUP BY`, assuming you wanted the positive/negative sums for a given group/column, e.g. the `ID` column.

Comment: Yes, you might do that, but your original question made no mention of this, hence I did not include it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a handy little function:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( Sample Decimal(10,2) );
insert into @Samples ( Sample ) values
  ( -10.00 ), ( -5.00 ), ( 0.00 ), ( 42.00 ), ( 8.00 );

-- Demonstrate separating values by sign.
select Sample,
  Sample * -Sign( Sign( Sample ) - 1 ) as Negative,
  Sample * Sign( Sign( Sample ) + 1 ) as Positive
  from @Samples;

-- Calculate the sums.
select Sum( Sample ) as Total,
  Sum( Sample * -Sign( Sign( Sample ) - 1 ) ) as NegativeTotal,
  Sum( Sample * Sign( Sign( Sample ) + 1 ) ) as PositiveTotal
  from @Samples;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this 
`select 
  sum(case when FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT>0 then FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT else 0 end)as Positive,
  sum(case when FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT<0 then FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT else 0 end) as Negative
from over_short`
or 
You can seperate store results in Temp table and Use it 
`select 
  sum(case when FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT>0 then FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT else 0 end)as Positive,
  sum(case when FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT<0 then FINAL_OVER_SHORT_AMOUNT else 0 end) as Negative
into #Temp from [dbo].[Temp]`

select 
  sum(Positive) as PositiveSum, sum(Negative) as NegativeSum
from #Temp